# I'm trying to check for acceptable height and weight and have the c++ compiler output why a candidate is rejected

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested-if

When only the weight is wrong, the following C++ code does not output any rejection message. What is wrong with my nested if-then-else checks?

```
char gender;      //INPUT  Gender of candidate
char genderOk;   //INPUT  Checks validity of input for each value
int  height;      //INPUT  Height of candidate
int  heightOk;    //INPUT  Range of valid heights for candidates
int  weight;      //INPUT  Weight of candidate
int  weightOk;    //INPUT  Range of valid weights for candidates

// INPUT - describe input here

cout << left;
cout << "Please enter candidate's information (enter 'X' to "
        "exit).\n";

do {
    cout << "Gender: ";
    cin.get(gender);
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    genderOk = gender != 'm' && gender != 'M' && gender != 'f' && gender != 'F';
    if(genderOk) {
        cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F *****";
        cout << endl;
    }
} while(genderOk);

do {
    cout << "Height: ";
    cin  >> (height);
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    heightOk = height >=24 && height <= 110;
    if (!heightOk) {
        cout << "***** Invalid height; please enter a height in "
                "inches between 24 and 110. *****";
        cout << endl;
    }
} while(!heightOk);

do {
    cout << "Weight: ";
    cin  >> weight;
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    weightOk = weight >= 50 && weight <= 1400;
    if(!weightOk) {
        cout << "***** Invalid weight; please enter a weight in "
                "lbs between 50 and 1400. *****";
        cout << endl;
    }
} while(!weightOk);

if (gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') {
    heightOk = height >= 65  && height <= 80;
    weightOk = weight >= 130 && weight <= 250;

    if (heightOk && weightOk) {
        cout << RESULT << "ACCEPTED!";
    }
    else {
        if (!heightOk) {
            if (!weightOk) {
                cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                  "HEIGHT and WEIGHT "
                                  "requirements.";
            }
            else {
                if(!weightOk) {
                    cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the"
                                      " WEIGHT requirement.";
                }
                else {
                    cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                      "HEIGHT requirement.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (gender == 'f' || gender == 'F') {
    heightOk = height >= 62  && height <=75;
    weightOk = weight >= 110 && weight <= 185;

    if (heightOk && weightOk) {
        cout << RESULT << "ACCEPTED!";
    }
    else {
        if (!heightOk) {
            if (!weightOk) {
                cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                  "HEIGHT and WEIGHT "
                                  "requirements.";
            }
            else {
                if (!weightOk) {
                    cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the"
                                      " WEIGHT requirement.";
                }
                else {
                    cout << RESULT << "rejected based on the "
                                      "HEIGHT requirement.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If weightOk is not false then it's true:

```
  if(!weightOk) {
    // weightOk=0
  } else {
    // weightOk=1 then
    if(!weightOk) {
      // never reaches here if weightOk=0
    }
  }
```